# /usr/bin/python3: плохой интерпретатор:

Tags: python, ubuntu

Не могу запустить python3. Получаю следующее сообщение:

> bash: /usr/bin/python3.4: Нет такого файла или каталога

Пробовал переустановить через:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3
```

но терминал говорит, что установлена самая последняя версия.

в папке /usr/bin файлы python34 и python3.4 выделены красным цветом.

Как мне вернуть 3-й питон?

**UPDATE.** После попытки переустановить через `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3` появляется следующая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE2**. `Попытка sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-minimal` привела к следующему:

```
E: Internal Error, No file name for python3-minimal:amd64
```

Попытка `debsums -s` тоже привела к неудаче:

```
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: плохой интерпретатор: Слишком много уровней символьных ссылок
```

Comment: внести изменения в текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: я дополнил ответ. p.s. текст всё-таки лучше выкладывать в виде текста, а не в виде картинки: во-первых, читается гораздо легче, во-вторых, текст индексируется и поисковыми серверами, и «местным» поиском.

Answer (score 3):

> Пробовал переустановить через: sudo apt-get install python3 но терминал говорит, что установлена самая последняя версия

для переустановки уже установленного(ых) пакета(ов) добавьте опцию `--reinstall`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall название(я)-пакета(ов)
```

---

**дополнение**. судя по приложенной картинке, при удалении пакета *postrm*-скрипт не может найти программу *py3clean*, а при установке пакета *postinst*-скрипт не может найти программу *py3compile*.

скорее всего, это файлы из пакета [*python3-minimal*](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python3-minimal&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) версии 3.4.0 или выше.

т.е., у вас либо удалён этот пакет, либо эти файлы, принадлежащие пакету. попробуйте переустановить данный пакет (*python3-minimal*), и лишь после **удачного** завершения процедуры вновь повторите попытку переустановить пакет *python3*.

---

возможно, у вас удалены файлы не только этого пакета. для поиска таких файлов рекомендую установить пакет *debsums* и выполнить:

```
$ debsums -s
```

эта программа проверит контрольные суммы файлов пакетов и отрапортует об изменённых/удалённых файлах.

Comment: Попробовал. Получил следующее:

dpkg: ошибка при очистке:
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 127
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.4.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: 1. вывод команд лучше давать в оригинале, а не на русском. для этого перед выполнением команды выполните `export LC_ALL=C`. 2. вывод команд лучше помещать в текст вопроса, т.к. в комментариях нет форматирования и форматированный вывод просто нечитабелен.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил текст вопроса.