# ошибка обновления GRUB в Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, xubuntu

```
omenra@omenraXU:~$ sudo update-grub
Создание конфигурационного файла grub...
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
mkdir: невозможно создать каталог «/var/lib/os-prober/mount»: Файл существует
mkdir: невозможно создать каталог «/var/lib/os-prober/mount»: Файл существует
завершено
omenra@omenraXU:~$
```

структура дисков:

```
omenra@omenraXU:~$ sudo fdisk -l
...
{пропущены RAM-диски}
...
Диск /dev/sda: 372,6 GiB, 400088457216 байтов, 781422768 секторов
Единицы измерения: секторов из 1 * 512 = 512 байтов
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Тип метки диска: dos
Идентификатор диска: 0x088af50d

Устр-во    Загрузочный     Start Конец Секторы   Size Id Тип
/dev/sda1                   2048 209733631 209731584   100G  5 Расширенный
/dev/sda2              209733632 781416447 571682816 272,6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5                   4096 209733631 209729536   100G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Записи таблицы разделов не соответствуют порядку разделов на диске.


Диск /dev/sdb: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 байтов, 3907029168 секторов
Единицы измерения: секторов из 1 * 512 = 512 байтов
Размер сектора (логический/физический): 512 байт / 512 байт
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Тип метки диска: dos
Идентификатор диска: 0x803416c9

Устр-во    Загрузочный      Start Конец Секторы  Size Id Тип
/dev/sdb1                    4094 2852132863 2852128770  1,3T  5 Расширенный
/dev/sdb2              2852132864 3907028991 1054896128  503G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdb5                 4200448  633346932  629146485  300G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb6               633350144 2852132863 2218782720    1T 83 Linux
/dev/sdb7                    6144    4200447    4194304    2G 82 Linux своп / Solaris

Записи таблицы разделов не соответствуют порядку разделов на диске.


omenra@omenraXU:~$
```

на sda стояла винда, но после начала проблем с GRUB ее снес.
Dосстанавливал GRUB  как описано в [help.ubuntu/wiki](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjwkYf_3MPOAhXGOBQKHZEQCWcQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp.ubuntu.ru%2Fwiki%2F%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BE%25D1%2581%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%25D0%25B0%25D0%25BD%25D0%25BE%25D0%25B2%25D0%25BB%25D0%25B5%25D0%25BD%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B5_grub&usg=AFQjCNHq_IG_pRPpbTkEe6-oq087Q8yggw&sig2=pv2go2ETRoxGVQOD_tBQLA&bvm=bv.129422649,d.d24)

по совету из комментария удалил папку `/var/lib/os-prober/mount` путем ее отмонтирования. При обновлении командой **update-grub** процесс далее `Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin` не идет.

спустя час решил прервать выполнение и получил следующее:

```
omenra@omenraXU:~$ sudo update-grub
Создание конфигурационного файла grub...
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
Найден образ linux: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
Найден образ initrd: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
```

прошел час, прервал с помощью **Ctrl+C**

```
^Cgrep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/raided-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/swaps-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/mounted-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
mkdir: невозможно создать каталог «/var/lib/os-prober/mount»: Файл существует
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/raided-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/swaps-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/mounted-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
mkdir: невозможно создать каталог «/var/lib/os-prober/mount»: Файл существует
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/raided-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/swaps-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/mounted-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
mkdir: невозможно создать каталог «/var/lib/os-prober/mount»: Файл существует
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/raided-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/swaps-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/mounted-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
mkdir: невозможно создать каталог «/var/lib/os-prober/mount»: Файл существует
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/raided-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/swaps-map: Нет такого файла или каталога
grep: /tmp/os-prober.9qhmxg/mounted-map: Нет такого файла или каталога

omenra@omenraXU:~$
```

Comment: Сам-то конфиг обновляется? Сдаётся мне, что в скриптах `os-prober` банально пропущена проверка на существование `/var/lib/os-prober/mount` и это не влияет на работу. По какой-то ошибке эта директория осталась существовать, пустая, и её можно просто удалить.

Comment: @Мелкий , попробую удалить.

Comment: отсоединил `/var/lib/os-prober/‌​mount` командой _umount_, запустил _update-grub_ и завис на строке: `Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin`

Comment: сообщения, выдаваемые программами, лучше приводить [на языке оригинала](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/507833/507841#comment612953_507841)

Comment: Тоже столкнулся с данной проблемой. Пока смог понять только, что виснет на определении загрузчика Windows. Если прерываю по Ctrl+C, то итоговый конфиг получается без загрузки Windows. Может это наведёт кого-то намысль что происходит не так.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, это не значит, что приложения не могут быть переведены. Так, в ubuntu-based системах почти все приложения имеют русскую локализацию. Даже консольные.

Comment: @СергейИванович, а как с железом? Древнее? Если да, то тогда понятно - у меня оно тоже много времени на слабеньком ноуте отбирало. Разве что не часы, а полминуты...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос был решен в 2016 году путем полной переинсталляции дистрибутива после ремонта мат платы. Железо было старое. После осмотра были выявлены и заменены **вздутые конденсаторы**.